# ElasticSearch Query Ignoring Additional Search Terms

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, full-text-search

I'm using ElasticSearch to build a free form search-as-you-type feature over multiple structured fields. The main fields people search on are `first_name`, `last_name`, and `city`.

**Problem**: The following two searches `David Salazar` and `David Salazar Denver` are returning the same results in which "Denver" appears to be ignored.

I'm assuming this is a problem with my query, but I'm stuck on how to change it to get what I'm looking for.

Here is the query:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields": [
        "first_name","middle_name", "last_name", "city", "county", "street"],
      "query": "David Salazar Denver",
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "use_dis_max": false
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

Here are the relevant parts of the index setup and field mapping

```
{
  "index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "type": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "county": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "synonym_autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "middle_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "synonym_autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "street": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        [...]
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms": [Long list of nicknames]
            },
            "autocomplete_filter": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "2",
              "max_gram": "15"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "synonym_autocomplete": {
              "filter": [
                "standard", "lowercase", "synonym", "autocomplete_filter"],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "autocomplete": {
              "filter": ["standard","lowercase","autocomplete_filter"],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        [...]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try doing a POST request if you're passing in JSON as additional search parameters. Set the header to Content-Type:application/json and pass in the JSON as the body. If that works for you, I'll expand this into an answer.

Comment: @Donglecow, it doesn't appear that it made a difference

Comment: No worries. That usually trips me up when querying with additional parameters so thought it was worth a guess. That's why I didn't put it as an answer straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Val was correct that the main problem was that `cross_fields` only works on fields that use the same analyzer.

So I created a new index with the code below and then used the `reindex` API to copy the data over to this new index

```
{
  "index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "type": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "county": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "synonym_autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "synonym_autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "middle_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "synonym_autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "street": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "synonym_autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          },
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        [...]
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms": [Long list of nicknames]
            },
            "autocomplete_filter": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "2",
              "max_gram": "15"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "synonym_autocomplete": {
              "filter": [
                "standard", "lowercase", "synonym", "autocomplete_filter"],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "autocomplete": {
              "filter": ["standard","lowercase","autocomplete_filter"],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        [...]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on [`cross_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) query documentation. You have an `operator` param there which is set to `OR` if absent. This means that your current query is searching for any term from `"David Salazar Denver"` in your fields list `["first_name","middle_name", "last_name", "city", "county", "street"]`. This basically means that document will be returned from search just when one word from search query is found in any of your fields.

Comment: One problem in his case is that cross-field works best when all fields in the fields list have the same analyzer, which is not the case here. As a result, as many field groups as there are different analyzers are created and you get the [same issues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#operator-min) are with `best_fields` and `most_fields`

Comment: @Val or @ Piotr - any suggestions on how to correct or change it for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Val - turns out you were right, the real problem was that the fields were using different analyzers.  When I tried to rewrite the query like the example in the docs you linked to, I got crazy results.  So I just re-indexed and applied the same analyzer to all of the fields.  If you want to go ahead and post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @dsal1951 and now you get better results?

Comment: Much better - it behaves exactly like I want it to where adding "Denver" to "David Salazar" is finding everyone with that name who lives in Denver.

Comment: Hello, reviving this, since I am facing a similar issue. I am using the same analyzer and also using `cross_fields` and `operator=AND`, however, in queries that include a keyword from the synonym list, the additional term gets ignored.